# Why python create a pointer of one variable to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, pointers, indexing

I was trying to resolve the following problem:

> Suppose a virus that infected a university database and changed the AR
>   (Academic Registry) of students. After some time, it has been found
>   that the AR generated by the virus (ARV = x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9)
>   the correct AR (ARC = y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9) could be obtained
>   through the following operations:
>
> y1 = x1, y2 = x2, y3 = x8, y4 = x7, y5 = x5, y6 = x6, y7 = x3, y8 =
>   x4, y9 = x9
>
> e.g., ARV = 197845602 --> ARC = 190645782
>
> Make a program that reads ARV and gives ARC.

My code looks like this:

```
pt = input('Type the AR affected by the virus: ')

arv = list(pt)
arc = arv

arc[2] = arv[7]
arc[3] = arv[6]
arc[6] = arv[2]
arc[7] = arv[3]

jarc = ''.join(arc)
print('\nCorrect AR:',jarc)
```

When you run the code, you see that the generated ARC its not the ARC of the example above. Why? I found it. The "arv" changes with the "arc", and it should stay immutable.

Seems to me that python create a pointer of the variable "arc" to "arv". Can anyone explain me why this happen? And how I can solve the problem correctly?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: Because in Python assignment doesn't copy anything.

Comment: Its a college assignment @Olian04

Comment: @Nelthar please read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: @Olian04 I always try to think hard on the questions. I only post here as my last resource, sorry.

Comment: Please read Ned Batchelder's [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I have sure that it will help me to understand better the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to copy the list contents, instead of the list descriptor:

```
arc = arv[:]
```

or

```
arc = arv.copy()
```

The *short* reason is that this is how the language is defined.  You can read about the history at various Python sites; the full explanation is beyond the range of StackOverflow's general purpose.

From a high level, this is how Python implements basic pointers: object assignment is to the original object, rather than making a copy.  This saves on spurious object duplication: if you want a new copy, you have to be explicit about allocating more storage.

Please note that your original, **arv**, is *not* "immutable": that is a Python technical term.  A list is a mutable object; a tuple is the immutable cognate.

Comment: Thanks for the help! xD

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do is make a copy:

```
arc = arv.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer xD